EKS Add dynamic cloudwath log group using FluentBit
I'm using this helm chart on EKS:
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/aws/aws-for-fluent-bit (version 0.1.34)
This is my config map:
fluent-bit.conf:
----
[SERVICE]
    HTTP_Server  On
    HTTP_Listen  0.0.0.0
    HTTP_PORT    2020
    Health_Check On 
    HC_Errors_Count 5 
    HC_Retry_Failure_Count 5 
    HC_Period 5 
    
    Parsers_File /fluent-bit/parsers/parsers.conf
[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Tag               <container_name>
    Path              /var/log/containers/backend-*.log,/var/log/containers/frontend-*.log
    DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
    multiline.parser  docker, cri
    Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines   On
    Refresh_Interval  10
    Tag_Regex (?<pod_name>[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace_name>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<container_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$  
    
[OUTPUT]
    Name                  cloudwatch_logs
    Match                 *
    region                us-east-2
    log_group_name        /eks/stage/fluentbit
    log_group_template    /eks/stage/fluentbit-${tag}
    log_stream_prefix     fluentbit-
    log_stream_template   $tag
    auto_create_group     true


What I want?
I want to have dynamic "Cloudwatch Log Groups" per ${container_name}
I would like those log groups:

/eks/stage/fluentbit/backend
/eks/stage/fluentbit/frontend

The fluentbit pods are running but I see in the logs:
[ warn] [env] variable ${pod_name} is used but not set

[ warn] [record accessor] translation failed, root key=tag

What I currently have?
In Cloudwatch Logs I see only one log group: /eks/stage/fluentbit- (The ${tag} is not working on log_group_template)
The Log Streams inside that log group are like:

fluentbit-backend (here is working the ${tag})
fluentbit-frontend (here is working the ${tag})

Also I don't like the naming convention for the Log Streams, I think it should be just: fluentbit-backend-$RANDOM with an extra timestamp maybe.
I don't want to add the kubernetes FILTER (we don't want the k8s metadata in the final log)
I want just the simplest solution, like a Tag_Regex using the path of the INPUT tail.
